# Run javacv example from eclipse

Tags: opencv, javacv

I downloaded this [javacv example](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/downloads/detail?name=javacv-examples-20120903-src.zip&can=2&q=) . when i try to run this code from eclipse  it shows this kind of error. please help me to solve this error. Thank you

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\sujan\AppData\Local\Temp\javacpp13165890902885\jniopencv_core.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:418)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:368)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:315)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.(opencv_core.java:131)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/javacv/issues/detail?id=90 + http://code.google.com/p/javacv/issues/detail?id=107

Answer (score 0):

You will have set the path for opencv libraries properly. Also make sure bitness of opencv and javacv should be same. You can find the instruction at the link below.

http://opencvlover.blogspot.in/2012/04/javacv-setup-with-eclipse-on-windows-7.html